# g++ cannot find boost header file

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

I just installed Boost 1.52.0, and I'm trying to use the Boost logging library (which I believe is now integrated into Boost).

I'm using the `/boost/log/trivial.hpp` file, and I'm trying to log messages as described [here](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html#log.tutorial.trivial). However, the compiler is unable to find the header file, and gives me the following error:

```
error: boost/log/trivial.hpp: No such file or directory
```

This is after my modifying the compiler and linker include paths.

My compile command is as follows:

```
g++ -O2 -I/Users/bar/Downloads/boost_1_52_0 -L/Users/bar/Downloads/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib foo.cpp
```

Any ideas as to what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

> I just installed Boost 1.52.0, and I'm trying to use the Boost logging
>   library (which I believe is now integrated into Boost).

Nope, it hasn't been integrated into boost yet. You can download it [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log/) and build it though. Boost 1.52 does not include any new libraries, it was an update for bug fixes, etc.

Also, you will need to link `boost_log` and `boost_system` (perhaps others too).

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a good tutorial on how to install Boost.log and then link the correct modules? I tried searching a bit, and couldn't find anything that was straightforward enough :(

Comment: I see you are using gcc. What platform are you on? There is a couple extra steps if you are using mingw, etc. [see here](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/supported_compilers.html).

Comment: MacOS, but I would like it to work on Ubuntu as well, since that will be the production machine.

Comment: If you copy the headers to your boost directory and libs directory, it should be as simple as `b2 --with-log` from your boost root directory.